# Slick2D Loading image wont work

Tags: java, graphics, slick2d

So I'm trying to load an image using Slick2D but for some reason I get the following error when I attempt to draw the image to the screen:

```
Sat Sep 28 16:37:59 NZST 2013 ERROR:null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.newdawn.slick.Graphics.drawImage(Graphics.java:1350)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Graphics.drawImage(Graphics.java:1399)
    at Game.render(Game.java:58)
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:703)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:456)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:361)
    at Game.main(Game.java:42)
Sat Sep 28 16:37:59 NZST 2013 ERROR:Game.render() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.render() failure - check the game code.
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:706)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:456)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:361)
    at Game.main(Game.java:42)
```

I am using this to load my image:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Textures {

    static Image grass;
    Game game;


    public Textures() {
            try {
                grass = new Image("grass.jpg");
            } catch (SlickException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

I am using this to draw my image:

```
for(int x = 0; x < app.getWidth(); x+=32) {
    for(int y = 0; y < app.getHeight(); y+=32) {
        g.drawImage(textures.grass, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever construct a Texture object? Otherwise the constructor will never be called and grass will be null.

Comment: Which line is line 1350 of `Graphics.java`?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a `NullPointerException` when trying to draw an `Image`, it's usually because the image loader didn't find the image at the location specified. If you're using `Eclipse`, be sure to store your images in a `source folder` (for instance named "resources"). This ensures images are moved to the `bin` folder on compilation (may require refreshing the source folder).

Regardless of your setup, be sure the path to the image is correct.